# code indent issue in frontend: How to remove annoying space at beginning of a line

Tags: front-end

I am using MMA 10.4.1

Very often I encountered this problem

[image]

This is an extraction of a `Module` (the last bracket is matching module). The `Module` runs without any problem. But notice the space at the beginning of mValue? I can't eliminate them now, whatever I do.

This situation often occurs when I copy and paste code.  I remember in previous version, I sometimes encounter this, but not that often.

**Anyone encountered this problem? Is there a simple fix for this?**

Comment: You have am extra square bracket at the end of the last line. That's a likely problem, unless this is all a continuation of some code above, in which case the indentation is automatic because that's good coding practice.

Comment: @march Hi, march. Sorry for my unclear post, there are codes before these lines, the final bracket is matched with previous Module bracket. It is not standalone. Anyway, have you encountered such indent issue when the code has no problem?

Comment: You might want to try using Code cells.

Comment: @chuy What is code cells?